# Change notifiaction bar color

Tags: android, xml

I'm creating an app and i'm wondering it there's a possible way to change the color of the notification bar. Thanks. [image]

Comment: The thing you point on your screenshot is not the notification bar but google search widget (that is not customizable).

Answer (score 2):

KitKat + devices can get system bar tinted.

I just found this library, it may be close to what you are looking for : 
https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint

But it will only work on KitKat+. Before that, there was no API to change these components, there were considered part of the system, not of apps.